# How I use jQuery "each()" inside HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Look at the HTML table below:

```js
$(document).on('change', '[name="item_inline"]', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $inp = $this.closest('tr').find('[name="rtn_qty[item_id]"]');
  var qty = $this.closest('tr').find('.qty').text();
  $inp.val(qty);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value="1"></td>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Return Qty</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 01</td>
      <td class="qty">150</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 02</td>
      <td class="qty">250</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 03</td>
      <td class="qty">350</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using this table, let say if I checked `select_all` check box, then I need to fill all the input under Return Qty column with the values of qty column. According to the above table input values should be (150,250,350). And other thing is, if I click on a checkbox inside `tr` then `input` of that row should be fill out the qty value of that same row.

I tried the similar way to `select_all` checkbox with `each` loop, But I confuse how I use `each` for this.

Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: _"This is the code so far I have"_ - There's a typo in that part: `funciton`

Comment: IMHO: If you're using event delegation then attach the event on the closest parent possible. In this case that would be the `<table>` (or `<tbody>`) and not `document`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `.each()`? [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) can set the value of all elements in the collection. In case of `select_all` walk the DOM up to the `<table>`, find all `rtn_qty[item_id]` elements and set their values with `.val()`

Comment: @Andreas personally I put *all* event handlers on `$(document)`, that way the features are completely independent of what's actually on the page. However, that's just me.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that should have been a IMHO... Added that to the comment

Comment: @Pointy if you don't care about performance then binding all events to `$(document)` is definitely the way to go. :-) But everyone can do however they like, as long as it works for them.

Comment: @cloned in my experience it makes absolutely no difference to performance. The events are going to bubble up through the DOM anyway, and the work necessary to match the event targets to selector strings is minimal in modern browsers on modern computing hardware. Plus it means a lot less work to rebind handlers when the DOM is frequently modified with content updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (using each on tr) is to reuse what you have:

Step 1: convert your handler to a function so that it can be reused.   Pass in `tr` as a parameter:

```
function selectRow(tr) {
  var inp = tr.find('[name="rtn_qty[item_id]"]');
  var qty = tr.find('.qty').text();
  inp.val(qty);
}
```

Step 2: change your handler to use function (and test it)

```
$(document).on('change', '[name="item_inline"]', function(e){
  selectRow($(this).closest("tr"))
})
```

Step 3: on the "all" change, get all the rows then pass each one to your function:

```
$("#select_all").change(function() {
  var rows = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody tr");
  rows.each((i, tr) => selectRow($(tr)))
});
```

Put together:

```js
$(document).on('change', '[name="item_inline"]', function(e) {
  selectRow($(this).closest("tr"))
})

$("#select_all").change(function() {
  var rows = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody tr");
  rows.each((i, tr) => selectRow($(tr)))
});

function selectRow(tr) {
  var inp = tr.find('[name="rtn_qty[item_id]"]');
  var qty = tr.find('.qty').text();
  inp.val(qty);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value="1"></td>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Return Qty</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 01</td>
      <td class="qty">150</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 02</td>
      <td class="qty">250</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 03</td>
      <td class="qty">350</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

With some small changes, we can make it more user friendly

```js
$(document).on('change', '[name="item_inline"]', function(e) {
  selectRow($(this).closest("tr"), $(this).is(":checked"))
  if (!$(this).is(":checked"))
    $("#select_all").prop("checked", false);
})

$("#select_all").change(function() {
  var rows = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody tr");
  var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
  rows.each((i, tr) => {
    selectRow($(tr), isChecked);
    $(tr).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", isChecked);
  });
});

function selectRow(tr, checked) {
  var inp = tr.find('[name="rtn_qty[item_id]"]');
  var qty = checked ? tr.find('.qty').text() : "";
  inp.val(qty);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value="1"></td>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Return Qty</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 01</td>
      <td class="qty">150</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 02</td>
      <td class="qty">250</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 03</td>
      <td class="qty">350</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

As noted in the comments, .val() has a an [overload](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) which allows you to make a single call to .val, eg:

```
$("#select_all").change(function() {
 $('[name="rtn_qty[item_id]"]').val(function(i, oldval) { 
  return $(this).closest("tr").find(".qty").text();
 }) 
});
```

there may be a better way to use .val() here, but it shows the concept.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution is catch change event of any table > tbody > input[type="checkbox"]
And catch change event of input[name="select_all"] and do click in the earlier inputs.

I hope it helps :)

```
//On change each table > tbody > input['type="checkbox"']
$('table tbody input[type="checkbox"]').change( function(){
  let parent = $(this).parent().parent();
  let qty = '';
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    qty = $(parent).find('.qty').first().text()
  }
  $(parent).find('input[type="text"]').val(qty)
} )

//On change input[name="select_all"]
$('input[name="select_all"]').change( function(){
  $('table tbody input[type="checkbox"]').click()
} )
```

```js
//On change each table > tbody > input['type="checkbox"']
$('table tbody input[type="checkbox"]').change( function(){
  let parent = $(this).parent().parent();
  let qty = '';
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    qty = $(parent).find('.qty').first().text()
  }
  $(parent).find('input[type="text"]').val(qty)
} )

//On change input[name="select_all"]
$('input[name="select_all"]').change( function(){
  $('table tbody input[type="checkbox"]').click()
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value="1"></td>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Return Qty</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 01</td>
      <td class="qty">150</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>    

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 02</td>
      <td class="qty">250</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>    

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="item_inline" value="1"></td>
      <td>Name 03</td>
      <td class="qty">350</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rtn_qty[item_id]" value="">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing an alternative solution. I really appreciate it.